# No electrical power triumph street tripler

Tags: electronics

the battery on my bike was dying, I needed to jump start it to get it running, however this time (it's never done this before) the battery started smoking, so I took it off straight away and brought a new one. I've checked all the fuses and they're okay, the new battery is putting out about 12.5 volts. There is not electronics at all when I turn the ignition key on. Help.

Comment: Are you entirely, completely, 100% sure you hooked up the positive and negative terminals correctly? If they were reversed, it could cause the exact scenario you describe.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  If you took it off fast enough, it's possible that you just hooked it up incorrectly, so you can try to just hook up the new one.  If that smokes though, you likely have a few wires crossed somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have replaced the battery with a new one, and it's definitely plugged in correctly (Positive to Positive, Negative to Negative), then the battery should be fine.

Then you want to double and triple check the fuses.
Because you get no lights, dash etc, It sounds like you have blown the Main Fuse.
I haven't been able to find a diagram of whether the main fuse is on this bike, however from another site.
"It is under the tank attached to the large starter relay. The obvious fuse you will see first is just a spare the actual main fuse is hidden there."

If this is blown and you swap in the spare it will probably fix it, if not, next diagnostic step would be to get a multi-meter, and in DC Volts mode probe with positive terminal of meter on Main Fuse and negative on battery negative.
You should see 12V, if you don't something in the wiring before the main fuse is broken. (or the Ground for the battery in the wiring has been damaged)

If you do see 12V, you can move on to the fuse box and see if you get voltage at the fuses. If you do, but bike doesn't work still, it may be better to have an auto-electrician take a look and see if they can find the broken component or wiring.